# Role playing dimensions other than Date/Time

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am working on a Data warehouse project and came across the concept of Role playing Dimension, I am wondering has anyone used a role playing dimension table other than Date/Time Dimension? because wherever i search about this, Date Dimension is the only example that has been given and i can't think of any other dimensions that plays multiple roles in similar manner!

Comment: On a sales order, off the top of my head, Person as order taker. Person as salesman. Person as Customer. Person as shipper. Person as receiver. Person as payer.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.doc/c_bp-multiplerelationships.html

http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/role-playing-dimension/

I think these two examples explain it fairly well.  Order Data, Ship Data, Closed date in the IBM reference to me is a good example of a roll playing dimension.  Three different "Roles" relating to the time dimension.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - the asker acknowledged that there's examples of Date and Time dimensions, and specifically asked for OTHER examples of uses.

Comment: So then if you understand this, then another example that is not date or time of a Roll Playing Dimension could be shipping location.  Where shipped from, what departing port location, what arriving port location, what final location.  Basically "Location in transit" for tracking shipping application could be an example with "Location" being the dimension.  But if you understand this I would think it would be easy to come up with another dimension for a Role Playing Dimension.

Comment: To come up with more role playing dimensions you have to come up with an item in a work flow that has a many to one relationship with your fact.  People who handled the product.  States the product traveled through, waypoints in transit.  Countries of origin of the parts the product is made up of.  Materials used in the products construction (Rubber, Aluminum, Titanium, Graphite for example)  Etc.